# Converting a working command into shell script file which gets arguments

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, xargs

Hi my working command is:

```
grep -l "my text" file*.ext|xargs ls -lart
```

this command is very useful for me and I wanted to create a shell file which does it with fewer typing, like this:

```
fn "my text" file*.ext
```

I came to this shell script file:

```
grep -l "$1" "$2"|xargs ls -lart
```

which is not working, even the first part is not working:

```
grep -l "$1" "$2"
```

which returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will need to take more than two arguments.

Before the shell executes `grep` in the command

```
grep -l "my text" file*.ext
```

the filename globbing pattern `file*.ext` is expanded to all matching filenames. The command line that is finally run will therefore be

```
grep -l "my text" file1.ext file2.ext file3.ext
```

(if those are the files that matches the pattern)

Therefore, your script may look like

```
#!/bin/sh

pattern=$1
shift

grep -l -e "$pattern" "$@" | xargs ls -lrt
```

Here, the pattern is saved into a variable, and then shifted off the list of command line arguments.  The remaining arguments is a list of filenames (if the filename globbing pattern on the command line matches) and is available in `"$@"`.

Make sure you double quote `$@`. This will make `$@` expand to the list of individually quoted command line arguments.

I've removed the `-a` option from `ls` as it's not needed when giving explicit filenames to list. I'm also using `grep` with `-e` to specify the pattern, as a pattern with an initial dash (`-`) may otherwise confuse `grep`.

---

If it wasn't for the sorting, I would have suggested the following `find` command instead of your pipeline (correctly handles filenames with spaces and newlines):

```
find . -type f -name "$filepattern" -exec grep -q -e "$pattern" {} ';' -ls
```

This looks for files with names matching what's in `$filepattern`, and with contents matching what's in `$pattern`, and then produces `ls -l`-like output.  The search is performed recursively in the current directory.

As part of a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

pattern=$1
filepattern=$2

find . -type f -name "$filepattern" -exec grep -q -e "$pattern" {} ';' -ls
```

*This* script would need to be called in such a way that the filename globbing pattern isn't expanded by the shell when calling it:

```
$ ./script.sh 'my text' 'file*.ext'
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it a bit safer, though relying on GNU extensions:

```
#! /bin/sh -
pattern=${1?pattern required}; shift
: "${1?no filename specified}"
grep -l --null -e "$pattern" -- "$@" |
  xargs -r0 ls -lrtd --
```

With `--null`/`-0`, we avoid problems with file names that contain blanks or quotes or backslashes.

With `-e "$pattern"`, we avoid problems with patterns that start with `-`.

With `--`, we avoid problems with file names that start with `-`.

With `-d`, we avoid possible confusions if files of type directory happen to match.

With `-r`, we avoid listing the current directory if there's no matching file.

Note that for a big number of files, `xargs` may choose to run more than one `ls` invocation with part of the file list, which means the output would not be properly listed by time.

Also note that `-` would mean stdin to `grep`, but the file called `-` in the current directory for `ls`. GNU `grep -l` would output `(standard input)` (or its translation in your language). If you want to specify the file called `-` in the current directory, use `./-` instead of `-`.